# Java Beans with Request and Session Scope

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, scope, javabeans

I want to create a web app which makes it possible to add friends into a list. 
For this reason I use JSF and Java Beans but now I have some serious problems.

First of all I created a friend class:

```
package at.fhjoanneum.ima11.listoffriendsjsf;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named("friend")
@RequestScoped
public class Friend implements Serializable{

    private String nickname;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public Friend() {
    }



 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null && obj instanceof Friend) {
    Friend other = (Friend) obj;
    return this.getNickname().equals(other.getNickname());
    }
    return false;
    }
    // getter, setter, equals, hashcode
    }
```

To store my friends I created another bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named("listOfFriendsBean") @SessionScoped
public class ListOfFriendsBean implements Serializable {

    private List<Friend> listOfFriends = new ArrayList<Friend>();


    public String addFriend(Friend friend) {
        if(!listOfFriends.contains(friend)) {
            listOfFriends.add(friend);
            return "index";
        } else {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "Your friend is already stored in the list!", null);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            return "index";    
        }
    }

    public List<Friend> getListOfFriends() {
        return listOfFriends;
    }
```

Last but not least I created a JSF file (only a part of it, this is just the form for adding the friends. Above of it is a table with the stored friends):

```
<p:panel header="Add friend">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="column" cellpadding="5">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Nickname" for="nickname"/>
                    <p:inputText id="nickname" required="true" value="#{friend.nickname}" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="Firstname" for="firstname"/>
                    <p:inputText id="firstname" required="true" value="#{friend.firstname}" />
                    <p:outputLabel for="lastname" value="Lastname"/>
                    <p:inputText id="lastname" required="true" value="#{friend.lastname}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>


            <p:commandButton value="Add" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" ajax="false" 
                             action="#{listOfFriendsBean.addFriend(friend)}" />
```

When I add the first friend everything works fine, but afterwards I get an error that the friend is already stored in the list and the values of the old friend are changed to the new values.
So I'm sure that my web app is using the same instance of friend but I don't get it since I used the request scope for the friend class. Shouldn't it create a new instance of friend for every request?
How can I solve this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've never used a RequestScoped bean like that. Normally, I'd make friend a property of a bean, not a bean itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not accustomed to such usage, but `addFriend` seems to need to make a copy of the Friend parameter here.

Comment: Thank you. I created a new instance of friend with the values of the parameter and now it works.
Although I used the request scope for friend it seems that there is just one instance of my friend class in the jsf file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override the equals method of the Friend bean:

```
    package at.fhjoanneum.ima11.listoffriendsjsf;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
    import javax.inject.Named;


    @Named("friend")
    @RequestScoped
    public class Friend implements Serializable{

        private String nickname;
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;

        public Friend() {
        }
    // getter, setter, equals, hashcode

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj){
            if(obj instanceof Friend && isEqual()){
               return true;
            }
            else 
                return false; 
        }

}
```

Comment: **isEqual** checks that two objects are meaningfully equal or not.

Comment: I added my equals method to my start posting.

Answer (score 0):

Plz check your equals method, if it contains correct business model object override (Friend)